# Image overlap issue with the latest Google Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been experiencing issues with the Google Chrome web browser `Version 32.0.1700.107 m`. Let me give you a simple schematic of an issue.

I have the following (pseudo) HTML to display two images -- the background and a clickable link on top of it:

```
<body>
<div class="page">
 <div class="tabs">
 </div>
 <div id="tab_twitter">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/name" title="Follow On Twitter" target="_blank">
  <img border="0" src="images/twtr_logo.png">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And CSS is defined as such:

```
.page {
    background-image: url("images/top_bkgnd.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    top: 0;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tabs {
    background-image: url("images/tabs_twtr.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 309px;
    height: 153px;
}

#tab_twitter {
    margin-left: 219px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 166px;
}
```

That approximately creates the following layout:

[image]

The issue happens on Google Chrome when my `tab_twitter` div is both invisible and unclickable. Note that this is laid out OK on the latest IE and Firefox. It also used to work in previous versions of Chrome.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are there any global styles in your css that affect images or anchors?

Comment: @Frankenscarf: You know, it must have been some intermediary Chrome version because when I restarted it, it updated itself to `33.0.1750.146 m` and the issue went away.